# Meteor app 403 forbidden

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, node.js, meteor

I have a meteor app which runs locally but on my linux ubuntu with nginx and passenger webserver it gives a 403 error.

I have changed the permission for the meteor and followed this simple guide found on this link [metoer setup on ububtu 14.04](https://tagrudev.com/blog/setting-up-meteor-with-nginx-and-passenger-on-ubuntu-1404)